# Transpiling es6 into es5

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, ecmascript-6

Ran into a problem today at work, wondering if anyone could offer some guidance. Im trying to accomplish roughly the following described below.

Files im working with:

1. **config.js** : config file using es6 syntax (particularly using import keyword).
2. **script.js** : node script written using node version that does not support the use of es6 syntax (particulary using import keyword). script.js aims to read the contents of config.js

   ```
   //config.js
   import _ from 'npm:lodash'
   import foo from '../otherRandomFile.js'
   var configObject = {
     randomConfigOne: true,
     randomConfigTwo: false
   }
   export default configObject;

   //script.js
   var config = require('../app/config.js)
   //cannot console log as below because script barfs
   //due to import being a reserved wrk
   console.log(config.randomConfigOne);
   ```

**Question:**
What do I have to do in script.js so that I can access the object exported by the config.js file. Right now the script is barfing about the fact that I'm trying to use es6 syntax in the file I'm accessing

Comment: put a .default after your require in script.js

Comment: Well, from your question title it looks like you already found the solution: use a transpiler. Did you try it?

Comment: @bergi Yes I have tried using a transpiler (babel), however, the devil is in the details. As you can see config.js imports other files (otherRandomFile.js) which in turn is also using es6 syntax, therefore I would have to somehow recursively transpile all imported files. Pretty much at this point the only solution I see is transpiling the entire directory. Was hoping there was a better way.

Comment: @dkorenblyum well, it seems I need another coffee <_< (sorry I missed that)

Comment: @dkorenblyum: So you already have a working solution? Even if not, show us that attempt! And what's wrong with transpiling all the files that are included?

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(config.default.randomConfigOne);
```

thus your module can export multiple items when you use

```
export default
```

it stored at `module.default`

Check this example https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=false&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Ces2015-loose%2Cstage-0%2Cstage-1%2Cstage-2%2Cstage-3&experimental=true&loose=false&spec=true&code=export%20default%20%7B%0A%20%20%0A%7D

babel converts 
`export default {}`
into

"use strict";

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports.default = {};
```

in such cases - just check transpiled code